# Angular drop-down toggle not working as expected

Tags: angular

Please could anyone assist. I am trying to enable a drop-down toggle in angular by creating a directive. When I use the selector in the div it does not work as expected. Using the "show" button in the drop-down class in the code below fixes the drop down items on the screen. I want to be able to toggle the class to show or hide the drop down items on click but doesn't seen to work as expected. Could anyone help out? Code below.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.show') isShown = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleShow(){
    this.isShown = !this.isShown;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Manage Recipe
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" appDropdown>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">To Shopping List</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Recipe</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete Recipe</a>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with your code  and make below changes to make it work.

- Apply the directive to `li` instead of the new `div`

  ```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" appDropdown>
  ```
- Change the class name to `open` instead of `show`

  ```
      @HostBinding("class.open") isOpen = false;
  ```

On a side note dont forget to add your directive in `app.module.ts.`

Sample code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhk538?file=angular.json

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually using "open" did not even show the drop down items till I used "show" within the div. So I was trying to toggle the class "show" to allow for the toggle functionality but still not working.

Comment: @Mr.Testa. Plz have a look at the code sample link in my updated answer!

Comment: Thanks very much. Still seems to not work when embedded in the main app. I would try to figure it out though. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Hope you register that in app.module.ts file :)

Comment: Yeah. I did. I don't know if it's any of the bootstrap classes interfering with the functionality. I'd try figuring out what the problem is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue.
I solved this problem by exporting the directive eg: exportAs: 'appDropDown'
and in your html component just add the #r="appDropDown" and assign the class
[ngClass]="{ show: r.isOpen }" to dropdown menu.

check the code down below for more details
[image]

[image]